# AngularJS binding the table although click cancel or cancel the change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
  var FormModule = angular.module('FormModule', []);
FormModule.controller("formCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $uibModal, $rootScope) {
$scope.dataItems=[{id:1,name:"bla",Description:"blabla"},
{id:2,name:"bla",Description:"blabla"}];
  //function Edit
    $scope.editColumn = function (data) {
        var ObjResolve = function () {
            return data;
        }
       
        $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'dataModal.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            resolve: {
                ObjResolve
            }
        }).result.catch(function (res) {
            if (!(res === 'cancel' || res === 'escape key press')) {
                //throw res;
            }
        });
    };
});
FormModule.controller("ModalInstanceCtrl", function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, $http, ObjResolve, $rootScope) {    
  $scope.data = ObjResolve;
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                   col1
                </th>
                <th>
                    col2
                </th>
                <th>
                    Options
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in  dataItems">
                <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.Description }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a ng-click="editColumn(data)" id="btnEdit">Edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="dataModal.html">
    <form name="modalForm">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Business Types</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label>name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="data.name" ng-readonly="isReadOnly" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="data.Description"  />                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-click="save()"
                    > Save
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </script>
```

I have an application that is a table with data and edit button that's open a modal to edit each row in the table,my problem is when I am trying to edit any value in the modal form and then click cancel;I found the updated value is changed in the table view .how can I solve that if it can solved using AngularJS?

Comment: Could you add some example code please? without it it would be impossible to help

Comment: I add an example Please check it @JavierFromMadrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your *dataModal.html* view you are using two-way data binding in the inputs with the unique instance of ObjResolve, so when you edit an input in the modal the change is populated in the object.

What I would do is to make a copy of the object when passing to the modal and assign it back in case you accept the changes:

**AngulaJS code**

```
var FormModule = angular.module('FormModule', []);
    FormModule.controller("formCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $uibModal, $rootScope) {
        $scope.dataItems=[{id:1,name:"bla",Description:"blabla"},
        {id:2,name:"bla",Description:"blabla"}];
          //function Edit
            $scope.editColumn = function (data) {
                var ObjResolve = function () {
                    return angular.copy(data);
                }

                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: true,
                    templateUrl: 'dataModal.html',
                    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        ObjResolve
                    }
                }).result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                    angular.forEach($scope.dataItems, function(item){
                        if(item.id == selectedItem.id){
                            item.name = selectedItem.name;
                            item.Description = selectedItem.Description;
                        }
                    });
                });


            };
        });
        FormModule.controller("ModalInstanceCtrl", function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, $http, ObjResolve, $rootScope) {

          $scope.data = ObjResolve;
          $scope.onAccept = function(){
              $uibModalInstance.close($scope.data);
          }

        });
```

HTML code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js" </script>
<table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                           col1
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            col2
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            Options
                        </th>
                    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="data in  dataItems">
                        <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data.Description }}</td>

                        <td>
                            <a ng-click="editColumn(data)" id="btnEdit">Edit</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="dataModal.html">
            <form name="modalForm">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Business Types</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="data.name" ng-readonly="isReadOnly" />

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Description</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="data.Description"  />

                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-click="onAccept()">
                        Save
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </script>
```

**UPDATE**

Added a JSFiddle with the described solution [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLj7b3su/2/)

Comment: awesome answer, but now I have a problem when accept, the table still have the old object values

Comment: updated to directly change the required item in $scope.items when the change is accepted

Comment: yes I know that's what I expected but actually when click accept the object not updated

Comment: have you checked the ".result.then" function in my example?

Comment: yes sure, and the object returned to it properly and the same problem still exist

Comment: just created a jsfiddle working with the expected behaviour: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/faGRk/)

Comment: sorry but it's not about what I want, please review it you may miss something

Comment: ouch! I did not save the JSFiddle, so it is not what I did. I will make it again later and ensure it is saved. sorry again

Comment: thank you very much it is working correctly.thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without the code but it's more than likely when you are editing, although you are pressing cancel the value is already binding therefore pressing cancel wouldn't be an undo button it would just close the edit option.

You would probably need to get the data loaded in a different way but as I said it is hard to tell without seeing it. Hope this helps!

Comment: I add an example Please check it

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in this case, when you open the model on click then declare another object and store the object whose properties you are going to change in edit form then on cancel button again put that cloned object variable into that original object from which you cloned it, it will resolve your issue.

Thanks 
Sanjeet

Comment: Please do you have some explanation with example or support docs?